# Get index of contain sublist from list java

Tags: java, list

I have string lists look like this:

```
 List<String> parentDataList:  {"this", "is", "a", "test", "string", "and", "a", "test", "other"} 
 List<String> child1:   {"a", "test"}
 List<String> child2:   {"this", "string"} 
 List<String> child3:   {"is", "a", "test"}
```

My expectation is that I want to check the parent list has contain **sequence** children list, then get the start and end indexs in parent list base on child list.
From above example:

```
 Parent contain child1 list, and return the indexes: [2 - 3] and [6 - 7]
 Parent doesn't contain child2 list because it isn't sequential.
 Parent contain child3 list, and return the index: [1 - 3]
```

I tried using `List.containsAll` method, but it doesn't care the order of list item, and I can't get start and end index from this method. 
I am looking for the fastest way to do this because my list has many data and I have to search from many input strings.
 Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**:
I need to get all index of sub lists are contained in parent list. For example, the parent contains child1 in two position: [2 - 3] and [6 - 7]

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: You are looking for [`indexOfSubList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList(java.util.List,%20java.util.List))

Comment: @Holger. Make that an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method [`Collections.indexOfSubList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) will give you the desired information.

> Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of the specified target list within the specified source list, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.
>   More formally, returns the lowest index i such that source.subList(i, i+target.size()).equals(target), or -1 if there is no such index. (Returns -1 if target.size() > source.size().)

```
int index=Collections.indexOfSubList(parentDataList, child1);
…
```

The index interval will be from `index`, inclusive, to `index+child1.size()`, exclusive. Unless the returned index is `-1`, of course. In the latter case the sublist was not found.

Comment: @R4j This is sure what you need but I don't know whether it satisfies your "fastest way" condition since indexOfSubList's implementation uses brute force technique. Just so you know :)

Comment: I would always try whether it works “fast enough” before thinking about alternatives.

Comment: I have tried this method in my application. Seem it is fast enough for my need. Searching in 100,000,000 records take 0.24 second (of course for my computer only). But it would be great if there is any better solution :)

Comment: I can imagine a variant of the Boyer–Moore algorithm adapted to `List`s or a parallel search but it’s not clear whether the gain would compensate the effort.

Comment: @Holger Sorry I forgot mention this one: I need to get all indexes of sub lists are contained in parent list as my updated question. The `Collections.indexOfSubList` only return the fist index from parent list that contains sub list as `Collections.lastindexOfSubList` only return the last occurrence . Is there any way to get all of them?

Comment: I updated the comment in my answer, in this case we can't have sublist inside another sublist because you are searching for consecutive strings, so you keep track of the list of the intervals you find

Comment: @R4j: just search in `parentDataList.subList(index+child1.size(), parentDataList.size())` for the next occurence.

Comment: @Holger I tried it. But I think it get more complicated because I have to loop through the parent list until getting the last occurrence by using a lot of `indexOfSubList`. In this case I think Alessio 's way easier and faster than it.

Comment: Maybe easier and faster, but definitely untested. I have my doubts that it handles all cases correctly. I strongly recommend building lot of test cases if you decide to go into that all-handmade direction. E.g. try to find `{ "a", "b", "a"}` inside `{ "a", "b", "a", "b" }` with that method…  Or `{ "a", "a"}` within `{"a", "a", "b", "a", "a"}`

Answer (score 2):

You can change @Alessio's code like this. It also works on your cases.

```
public List<Interval> getIntervals(String[] parent, String[] child) {
    List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    Interval interval = new Interval();

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        if (child[j].equals(parent[i])) {
            j++;
            if (j == 1) {
                interval.start = i;
            }
            if (j == child.length) {
                interval.end = i;
                intervals.add(interval);
                interval = new Interval();
                j = 0;
            }
        } else {
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    return intervals;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it manually :

```
public static List<Interval> getIntervals2(String[] parent, String[] child) {
    List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Launch.Interval>();

    for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
        if (child[0].equals(parent[i])) {
            Interval interval = new Interval();
            interval.start = i;
            intervals.add(interval);
        }
    }

    ListIterator<Interval> iterator = intervals.listIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Interval interval = iterator.next();
        for (int j = 1, i = interval.start + 1; i < child.length; i++, j++) {
            if (!child[j].equals(parent[i]))
                iterator.remove();
        }
        if (interval.start + child.length - 1 < parent.length - 1)
            interval.end = interval.start + child.length - 1;
        else
            iterator.remove();
    }

    return intervals;
}
```

Comment: You should add else condition where it finds a match but the remaining ones dont or it will traverse whole parent list even if it don't have that sublist and @R4j wanted a fast solution. Like `else if(j>0) return null;` But the rest will just work as indexOfSubList method since it is also a bruteforce solution.

Comment: @MehmetSedatGüngör as Holger said, I tested on this case: { "a", "b", "a"} inside { "a", "b", "a", "b" } and the result is wrong. Could you take a look?

Comment: you are right, I changed the code but I increased the complexity, I'll upvote your code also ;)