# How to check whether a list is a subset of another list, regardless of order

Tags: java, list

How can I tell if String list is subset of another string Parent List?

```
 List<String> parentDataList:  {"abc", "def", "ghi", "xyz"} 
 List<String> child1:   {"def", "abc"} // this is a subset, regardless of order
 List<String> child2:   {"1234", "ghi"}   // not a subset, because 1234 not exist
 List<String> child3:   {"ghi", "xyz, "abc"}  // this is a subset, regardless of order
```

This answer accounts for sequence order, which I do not care about.

[Get index of contain sublist from list java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223487/get-index-of-contain-sublist-from-list-java)

```
return Collections.indexOfSubList(parentDataList, child1) != -1;
```

Comment: `new HashSet<String>(parentDataList).containsAll(child1)` maybe?

Comment: hi @GreenCloakGuy feel free to write as answer, and I can send points, thanks , also please upvote question if you can

Comment: You don't technically need the HashSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the parent list contains all of those defined in child list.
Let's say you've parentDataList as

```
List<String> parentDataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and all of these `"abc", "def", "ghi", "xyz"` added.
And do similar for all the child list you desire.

You can write whether parent data list has all of the data contained by child list as follows :

```
int parentSize = parentDataList.size();
int childSize = childDataList.size(); // after creating and adding element to child data list
boolean isSubset = parentDataList.containsAll(childDataList) && parentSize >= 
childSize;
System.out.println(isSubset);
```

Question arises what to do when list contains duplicate ? It's better to use `Set /HashSet` because it **avoids duplicates** and it's easier to maintain. But if you're sure to add only unique elements in `ArrayList` too, I believe this should work.

**NOTE :**
Mathematically set has unique elements but you're declaring them as List which can has duplicates, so I have written with && operators and compared their size too.

Comment: thanks, do we need parent size filter?

Comment: @mattsmith5 if you're checking for subset , you're going to check that in parent list. So , you'll filter from parent list. Super set is bigger or at least equal to the subset in terms of size that's why I've also compared their size. It can work even without those, but I've assumed my own test cases as you've not provided them. Just run the code above with few of your test cases and also adding the duplicates, you'll understand what I mean.